# Pivot string data from rows to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a dataset as follows:

```
Sales_Doc    Item   SLNo    SubCt    SubRef
----------------------------------------------  
48145         10    1         R      16213000
48145         10    1         J      28776213
48145         10    2         J      28776214
48145         10    1         M      39375228
```

And I would like to have the following result

```
Sales_Doc   Item    SLNo       J            R           M
-------------------------------------------------------------
48145         10    1       28776213    16213000    39375228
48145         10    2       28776214    16213000    39375228
```

I have tried several ways but none gets me the correct result. Can someone help with SQL Server code?

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  Additionally, is SQL Server or Postgresql? We're talking about two different SQL engines with different features.

Comment: Post the "most close" way you got to. Where did the data for R and M come from for the SLNo 2 row, given that the source data doesn't contain it? (SLNo1's data? What happens if it is the SLNo 1 row that doesn't contain that data next time?)

Comment: Additional question: Is your SubCt limited to J/R/M or can be there appear arbitrary values?

Comment: @Arvo makes a good point; if there are, the frontend should be doing the pivot

Comment: Hi J/R/M are the only options possible in the full dataset

Comment: What is the logic behind getting that result?

Answer (score 0):

If the result was a typo and you wanted to get J\R\M per Sales_Doc, Item, SlNo then you could use PIVOT like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
pivot (MAX(SubRef) FOR SubCt IN ([R],[J],[M]) ) pvt;
```

[DBFiddle demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0d0858fea16e29f9258908f4547767f3)